# Center attribute of BoxCollider2D not working?

Tags: unity

I've been trying to make a laser beam for my 2D shmup. I've set up a LineRenderer, along with a box collider 2D, and I've noticed that the center of the collider is positioned at one end of the line.

My settings are

Line

- 2 Elements

  - (1)0x 0y 0z
  - (2)0x 0y 10z
- Not using World Space
- Rotated 90 on the Z axis (to face the 2D camera)

I thought the Center attribute would align the box collider, but changing the X value seems to do nothing. Is it possible to align the box collider such that it is around the beam, and not sticking outside of it?

Image reference: [image]

Comment: So do you want the collider around the line render object?

Comment: Yep. I've messed about with the line renderer values and it appears that you have to put the Z value of point (1) to a negative to match the boxCollider. Surely that can't be the right way to do this? Seems counter-intuitive...

Comment: I see you tagged this question as Unity, but who is responsible for drawing the objects, it might be a rendering bug and not a physics thing (thought that is unlikely if Unity renders this for you).

Comment: The object is a LineRenderer with a material attached to it to make it look like a laser beam. I'm not sure how this is a rendering bug.